# WordPress subcategory slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I have on my WP website URL structure for categories like this:

```
domainname.com/category/
domainname.com/category/subcategory/
```

How can I remove `/category/` for each `/subcategory/`

I need this version: `domainname.com/subcategory/`

I read a similar problem here, but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from WordPress settings -> Permalink settings.
For details see:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks
https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Comment: No, its not possible. Via Permalink settings Im not able to change the SUBCATEGORY slug.

Comment: What about adding domainname.com/%subcategory%/ in permalink setting in custom structure field?